# Having trouble downloading PyQt5 Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I can't download the pyqt5 designer through pip using this command:
"pip install pyqt5-tools"
I also tried pip3 if there's any difference. It's just errors:

```
ERROR: Cannot install pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.0.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.1.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.14.2.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.0.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.1.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.0.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.0.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.2.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.3.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.3.3.1, pyqt5-tools==5.15.3.3.2, pyqt5-tools==5.15.4.3.0.3, pyqt5-tools==5.15.4.3.1 and pyqt5-tools==5.15.4.3.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
```

That's just one of them out of like 4 or 5. At the end it's saying:

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

```
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

So, I tried doing what they told me to do which is to use "pip install pyqt5-tools --no-deps"
It worked and said it successfully installed. Don't really see it anywhere though. I used to have it with anaconda before I deleted anaconda not realizing that it was downloading with anaconda. Or at least I think. There is still the designer.exe, but when I try to run it, I get messages saying that libpng16.dll, zlib.dll, and icuin58.dll are missing and it can't run. I've tried deleting and reinstalling everything twice now. Sorry if I sound super clueless, I'm super new to everything.

Comment: use python 3.9, not python 3.10

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've been stuck on this for hours.